# Vertical scrollbar does not stop at the bottom of the ag-grid grid

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid

I have an [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0) in an Angular application. On one of the pages, when data is displayed the horizontal scrollbar gets hidden and the vertical scrollbar does not stop at the bottom of the grid. What could be causing this behavior?

[image]

There is no DIV surrounding the grid on the page.

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width:100%;height:70%;" 
    rowSelection="multiple" 
    class="ag-fresh" 
    [rowData]="reportData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

On another page in the same application the bars are displayed as follows:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried setting that height to 100% instead of 70%?

Comment: I did. That had no effect on this behavior.

Comment: Are you sure the grid is not being hidden by something? Is there an overflow somewhere on that page? To me it seems the grid is going behind another layer and the scroll bar just tries to reach the end of it.

Comment: What you are suggesting makes a ton of sense and was the first thing I checked. That border you see in the .gif is the border of ag-grid's numerous divs that are spit out to the page. I have no manual control over those.

Comment: Is that happening on all browsers or just Safari? And what is that class="ag-fresh"? Do the other grids ( the ones that are working ) have the same class?

Comment: This is happening in Chrome and IE. I have not tested Safari.

Comment: could you create a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) that reproduces the error?

Comment: I will try doing that in the near future. At this point, it appears that this behavior is the result of some tweaking of CSS for ag-grid that the other developer did in order to have the text displayed vertically in the column headers.